# get all keys as single string from TDictionary class

Tags: delphi

is there any smarter way ( with less code) to go get all keys from a TDictionary  as a single string, comma separated

```
var
  FDicList : TDictionary <String, Integer>;
  KeyStrList: TStringlist;
  KeyName: string;
begin

  /// result as comma text
  KeyStrList := TStringlist.Create;
  try
    for KeyName in FDicList.Keys do
      KeyStrList.Add(KeyName);

    All_keys_as_string := KeyStrList.CommaText;
  finally
    KeyStrList.Free;
  end; 

end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the keys don't contain a comma itself you can just write:

```
All_keys_as_string := string.Join(',', FDicList.Keys.ToArray);
```

Comment: To use `string.join` you need to have `TStringHelper` active which means having `SysUtils` in your `uses` clause and not overriding that helper with one from another unit or in your own code (as only one helper (the last one defined) can be active on any type).

Comment: @RobLambden, better don't mislead people to shoot them into their own foot.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  How is saying that they need to `use SysUtils` misleading?  How does that make them 'shoot them into their own foot?'  Your answer is clean and concise but it requires SysUtils and doesn't state that.

Comment: @RobLambden: In most cases, it would be a bad idea to define your own helper for the `string` type.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, that is exactly what I meant.